# iSeries connection error with IBM DB2 Connector Core

Tags: .net-core, ibm-midrange, db2-400

When we migrated from .NET framework to .NET core, we had to change the format of our iSeries connection string from using `Server=` to using `Data source=` and to include port#, but also we had to include `Database=` because without it the connection string could not be assigned to a connection due to an "Invalid argument" exception. With absolutely anything for a database, we always get a uniform error message:

```
ERROR [08004] [IBM] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name \"QSYS              \" was not found at the remote node.
```

(Notice extra spaces in the DB name)

No matter what we supply for a database, the error is always the same. We tried our actual library name similar to `app0123` that is reported by `DSPLIB` or `QSYS` etc.

We also tried databases reported by `DSPRDBDIRE` named similarly to `IHST0123` but in this case the error was different:

> ERROR [42968] [IBM] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.

We know that there is no licensing problem with the server because it is our production environment that many applications in Java and C# connect to.

Our usual practice is that if an application `App1` connects, it uses `app1` user name and `app01`, `app02` etc schemas, `app01` being the default one. Therefore, we only ever had the iSeries host name like `IHST01` etc in the connection string, and we added user ID and password through the connection string builder.

We are having no issues connecting through .NET core connector to DB2 LUW since database on it is very apparent and unambiguous. Since we never had to specify an iSeries database under .NET framework, it is not clear what it has to be. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

The library (aka schema) name is not the database name.

The *LOCAL entry in `DSPRDBDIRE` should be your DB name.

A better tool is IBM Access Client Soultions (ACS) "Database -->Schemas" tool which has a UI like so:

[image: IBM ACS Schemas]

On the connected server (ut29p63.rch.stglabs.ibm.com),  there are (at least) two databases:

- ut29p63
- Dbtest

I'm surprised you don't think the DB name was needed for .NET Framework or Java as I've always needed them.  If you've only got one database on your IBM i, as is common for smaller boxes, it's possible the DB name matches the system name.

Judging from the license error message, you are getting connected.

However, the .NET Core nuget packages use the IBM Db2 Connect driver.  This driver is included for Db2 for LUW, and with an appropriate and optional license allows connecting to IBM Db2 for i or IBM Db2 for z/OS.

In other words, the Db2 Connect driver can always connect to Db2 LUW but you'll have to pay for an enhanced license to connect to IBM i or IBM z/OS.  See [IBM Db2 Connect License Types](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-connect-license-types)  You'll need an Enterprise license or an Unlimited Edition for System i.

If you were using Db2 Connect driver for your .NET Framework, the same license will work for .NET Core (assuming the Db2 Connect versions match).

However, if you were using the free ODBC/OLEDB/ADO driver for .NET Framework, then you'll need the Db2 Connect license for .NET Core.

Comment: Where is the license to iSeries in the full framework connect and if it is there, then why is it not included in Core? I do not believe I said anything about other technologies.

Comment: We used the reference to client access DLL under framework. I do not see a license file there.

Comment: Now I understand. IBM has taken everyone who runs iSeries hostage at the point where we may migrate to Core. Thanks, but no thanks. We do not negotiate with terrorists.

Comment: @RixaCivad - If you were using Db2 Connect with .NET Framework, you should be able to also use it for Core. You can always use ODBC (which is free) regardless.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to use full framework assemblies from a Core app. We have already migrated to ODBC anyway.