# How do I create a .NET windows app to connect and call an AS400 stored procedure?

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET and I need an app to call a stored procedure on the AS400. First, it seems to want a database name to connect to. This particular stored procedure does not return a dataset.

Comment: if possible I would have a PHP server running on the AS400, then access the SQL procedure thru a PHP web service.  You call the web service using cURL or its .NET equivalent.  Then the PHP web service uses the db2_connect, db2_prepare, db2_bind_param, ... functions to call the SQL stored procedure.  Very flexible. And more secure than opening the entire AS400 database to access from the .NET code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iSeries connection error with IBM DB2 Connector Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513640/iseries-connection-error-with-ibm-db2-connector-core)

Comment: Certainly looks like it. I’m travelling now, will check when I get back. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps

- Create stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio
- Create your project web/Desktop etc
- Create the connection string and connect your app with your DB
- Call this stored procedure in your application

Comment: I am having a problem with I know will sound like a dumb question. It keeps wanting the database name to connect to. What database? On my PC, on the As400? How do I create it it and where? I don’t need a database, I am just calling a stored procedure. I have the sp up and working.